# How to solve race condition in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to wait on both "Players" to get got, then do some other stuff.
Shouldn't it just be running #1 and then finishing then #2? Documentation on this online is conflicting.
Edit: Perversely, I don't care about the order, I just need to get both of them, and ***THEN*** do some other stuff. I tried the accepted solution, as it should order them, but adding a

```
.then(() => {
  console.log('PeepsList', peepsList)
})
```

somehow ***STILL*** comes back with only one player...I logged it to make sure and yes, it's 1.then.2.then.3 and the responses are 1 3 2!

```
challongeClient.matches.index({
  id: args[0],
  callback: (err, data) => {
    console.log(err, 'PLAYERS::')
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
      if (value.match.state === 'open') {
        // GET PLAYER 1
        try {
          challongeClient.participants.show({
            id: tournamentURL,
            participantId: value.match.player1Id,
            callback: (err, data) => {
              console.log(err)
              let peep = message.guild.members.cache.find(member => member.id === data.participant.misc)
              peepsList.push(peep.user.username)
              console.log('GET PLAYER 1', peepsList)
              console.log('GET PLAYER 1', peepsList[0])
              console.log('GET PLAYER 1', peepsList[1])
            }
          })
          // GET PLAYER 2
          challongeClient.participants.show({
            id: tournamentURL,
            participantId: value.match.player2Id,
            callback: (err, data) => {
              console.log(err)
              let homie = message.guild.members.cache.find(member => member.id === data.participant.misc)
              peepsList.push(homie.user.username)
              const [p1, p2] = peepsList
              console.log('GET PLAYER 2', peepsList)
              console.log('GET PLAYER 2', p1)
              console.log('GET PLAYER 2', p2)
            }
          })
        } catch (error) {
          console.log('ERORORRORORROROEROROROROR')
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

***EDIT***
Code from implementing solution:

```
const getPlayer = (playerXId) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        challongeClient.participants.show({
          id: tournamentURL,
          participantId: playerXId,
          callback: (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
              reject(err);
              return;
            }
            let peep = message.guild.members.cache.find(member => member.id === data.participant.misc)
            peepsList.push(peep.user.username)
            resolve();
            console.log('RUNNING GET PLAYER', playerXId, peepsList)
          }
        });
      });
    }
...
 if (value.match.state === 'open') {
              // GET PLAYERS
                        getPlayer(value.match.player1Id)
                        .then(() => {
                          getPlayer(value.match.player2Id)
                          return peepsList
                        })
                        .then((peeps)=> {
                          console.log('PPPPPPPEEEEEEEEPS',peeps)
                        })
                      }
```

Response:

```
RUNNING GET PLAYER 147860148 [ 'Studstill' ]
PPPPPPPEEEEEEEEPS [ 'Studstill' ]
RUNNING GET PLAYER 147860153 [ 'Studstill', 'ChunkLord' ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two method calls will be executed immediately one after the other, and the callbacks will only be called once the result has been received, which could be any length of time. There's no guarantee that player 1 will even come back before player 2.

To guarantee the order, you could put the logic to get player 2 into the callback of player 1, or wrap it in a function which is called from that place, which is ugly.

Preferably, you could convert it to a promise. Something like this:

```
const getPlayerOne = (player1Id) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    challongeClient.participants.show({
      id: tournamentURL,
      participantId: player1Id,
      callback: (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
          return;
        }
        let peep = message.guild.members.cache.find(member => member.id === data.participant.misc)
        peepsList.push(peep.user.username)
        resolve();
      }
    });
  });
}

const getPlayerTwo = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) = {
    // Similar thing...
  });
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
getPlayerOne(value.match.player1Id)
  .then(() => getPlayerTwo(value.match.player2Id))
  .catch((error) => console.error(error))
```

You could probably even refactor it to to get player 1 and player 2 from the same function with different arguments.

Comment: It seems like this should work, but I still cannot figure out how to wait on both of them. I absolutely do not understand how chained '.then' can possibly be running before the previous is complete --- isn't that the sole function of .then? I made some edits to the post with more information.

Comment: Correct, `then()` will execute only when the previous promise resolves. If you need to wait for the second one to also complete, add another `then()` before the `catch()`

Comment: I know, this is kind of why I'm losing it over this. Is there something happening in the challongeClient module that could be screwing this up? Because I'm 100% getting the last chain before the second player.

Comment: I don't know what happens in the challongeClient, but maybe it is to do with your data loop? Every pass over the loop will run a separate async process,with no guaranteed order.

Comment: I dropped this into the "getPlayer" function, and I'll just do whatever here and see if that works out? Seems hacky though:
i++
if (i > 1) {
              console.log('I = 2', peepsList, i)
              i = 0
            }