# How to wait for the final result of a for loop with API calls?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

This loop is going to run an arbitrary amount of times, and I want to get the result out of it after them all. Anything I try (promisifying, async/await, nesting functions, et al) seems to be a dead end. I don't get why I cannot just stick a .then on the API call, or on the function I made here. But I suspect the problem is more fundamental with my understanding, because I can't seem to even get just the "data" to return...same inability to wait on the API call. Wrapping it in a promise loses the "data" and pulling it with the "for loop" inside there doesn't work either. This is making me question my entire progress with JS/implementing other people's APIs.

```
  const gotPeeps = () => {
      challongeClient.tournaments.show({
      id: tournamentURL,
      callback: (err, data) => {
         //return data //doesnt return "data" from gotPeeps?
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data.tournament.matches)) {
            if (value.match.state === 'open') {
              peepsList.push(value.match.player1Id, value.match.player2Id)
              console.log(peepsList)
    }}}})}
    gotPeeps()
```

***EDIT***
To the comments:
I'm trying to get the results after the for loop is complete.
The "loop" I was referring to is the "for of" over the data Object.
"Putting the code after the loop but inside the callback" does not work. I have a previous question in my week of failing to solve this:
[How to solve race condition in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67862434/how-to-solve-race-condition-in-javascript)
Here is the whole thing, with some past versions commented out.:

```
const tournamentModel = require('../models/tournamentSchema')
require('dotenv').config()
const challonge = require('challonge');

module.exports = {
  name: 'getmatches',
  aliases: ['gm'],
  cooldown: 0,
  description: 'Get Challonge data into console.',
 
  execute(message, args, cmd, client, Discord, profileData) {
    let peep = ''
    let peepsList = ''
    const tournamentURL = 'TESTING_Just_Sign_Up_If_You_See_This850587786533011496'
    const challongeClient = challonge.createClient({
      apiKey: process.env.CHALLONGE_API_KEY,
    })
  
  const getPlayer = (playerXId) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      challongeClient.participants.show({
        id: tournamentURL,
        participantId: playerXId,
        callback: (err, data) => {
          if (err) {
            reject(err);
            return;
          }        
          peep = data.participant.misc
          peepsList.push(peep)
          console.log(peepsList)
          console.log('RUNNING GET PLAYER', playerXId, playerIndexCount)
          resolve(peepsList);  
          }
        });
      });
    }
    
    

    const peepsList = []
    const matchList = []
    const gotPeeps = () => {
      challongeClient.tournaments.show({
      id: tournamentURL,
      include_participants: 1,
      include_matches: 1,
      callback: (err, data) => {
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data.tournament.matches)) {
            if (value.match.state === 'open') {
              peepsList.push(value.match.player1Id, value.match.player2Id)
              console.log(peepsList)
            }
          }
      }
        
              /*// GET PLAYERS
            getPlayer(value.match.player1Id)
            .then(() => {
            getPlayer(value.match.player2Id)
          }) 
        }
          */
                    
                  }
            )         
      }
      
    gotPeeps()
    }}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. `gotPeeps` is a recursive function but I don't see where it ends and `challongeClient.tournaments.show` has a callback which you like to await before calling `gotPeeps` again? In what seems to be an infinite loop?

Comment: I see the `}}`  at the end makes it look like the `gotPeeps` call is inside the function but it's not. Maybe worth removing those trailing `}}` as they don't belong to anything right now.

Comment: Which loop are you talking about? If you mean the iteration of `Object.entries`, just put your code right after the loop, but still inside the callback.

Comment: Please show us how you tried to promisify the code, and the where you want to return what. Also where's the `peepsList` declared?

Comment: The answer attempt below is exactly how I've attempted it, Bergi, and the same thing I meant by "code after the loop but in the callback" doesn't work, it just dips out and happily "resolves" the promise as undefined, which shouldnt be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this function return a promise and await the function (as long as your function is an `async` function)

```js
const gotPeeps = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const peepsList = []; // declare the empty array to e filled

    challongeClient.tournaments.show({
      id: tournamentURL,
      callback: (err, data) => {
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data.tournament.matches)) {
          if (value.match.state === "open") {
            peepsList.push(value.match.player1Id, value.match.player2Id);
          }
        }
        resolve(peepsList); // resolve the promise with the filled array
        // TODO: handle reject
      },
    });
  })
};

(async () => {
  try {
    const result = await gotPeeps();
  } catch (error) {
    // TODO: handle error
  }
})();
```

Comment: +1                                  for the TODO :-) Adding handling of `err` should be easy to add though

Comment: I might also add a try catch to show how to handle the error

Comment: I love the TODOs! However, this is the exact problem I cannot solve! Your version is the one I have tried already in a few ways, and any attempt to promisify this API call are I think resulting in "resolving" it before the call returns! Here is the error: Object.entries(data.tournament.matches)) {
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.entries (<anonymous>)
    at callback

Comment: Well that error message means the data you get back does not have an entry at `data.tournament.matches`. I don't know the shape of your data so I can't help you.

Comment: An angry comment is not going to help you. I'm trying to help you but there is not enough information here to do just that. console.log `data` before your for of loop and post the result in your question.

Comment: The downvotes before I had even responded were pretty disheartening. I appreciate the attempts, really I do, but it irked me to have it dismissed as am oversight on my end with regards to the data structure. I'll edit that in, thanks for the additional support.